# Preventing Windows from displaying "insert last disk" message

Tags: windows-10, usb, zip

I inserted a USB stick into my PC. The USB stick contained a single ZIP file only (not part of multiple ZIP files). The ZIP file was somehow corrupted. Windows Explorer showed this message immediately after inserting the USB stick (and there's no `autorun.inf` and even then, that's disabled on my machine):

[image: Windows Explorer asking for the last disk of a multi volume set.]

From the 1990's I know that we sometimes needed to insert Floppy disks. I don't think it works the same way with USB sticks. As soon as I disconnect the USB stick to insert another USB drive, the drive letter is gone, which was not the case for A: and B: floppy drives back then. Whenever I insert the "first disk" again, it will re-detect the drive and everything starts over again. It's an endless loop.

**Is it possible to turn this message off? How?**

I am not extracting anything. The message appears automatically after inserting the USB stick into the computer. The message is displayed by Windows Explorer, which I confirmed by using Process Explorer's "Find Window" functionality.

It's also not a self-extracting archive. It's Flutter for Windows, downloaded from [the Windows install page](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/windows/mobile?tab=download) , resulting in [the flutter 3.16.9 ZIP](https://storage.googleapis.com/flutter_infra_release/releases/stable/windows/flutter_windows_3.16.9-stable.zip). But, as noted, my ZIP file became corrupted.

Comment: "Is it possible to turn this message off?" - The best way to avoid this message is to store all the archive files in a single location.  You recieved this message, before you even attempted, to open the archive file?  If so what software did you use to write the files to the drive?  AutoRun on removable storage has been disabled, by default, for more than a decade.

Comment: @Ramhound: It is only a single ZIP file, but it got corrupted somehow. Autorun is disabled on my machine and there is no autorun.inf either

Comment: What software are you using to extract the file? Am I understanding this request for additional files was automatic, and not due to you, trying to extract the file(s)?

Comment: @Ramhound: I am not extracting anything. The message appears automatically after inserting the USB stick into the computer. The message is displayed by Windows Explorer, which I confirmed by using Process Explorer's "Find WIndow" functionality.

Comment: Was this archive by chance a self extracting archive when it was created?

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling Windows automatic handling of Zip-compressed files, if you use other applications, such as [7-Zip](https://7-zip.org/). In Regedit, remove keys `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CompressedFolder\CLSID` and `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.zip\CLSID`, or create the following as a .reg script and run it to do so:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CompressedFolder\CLSID]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.zip\CLSID]
```

The following .reg script will restore Windows direct access to Zip files:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CompressedFolder\CLSID]
  @="{E88DCCE0-B7B3-11d1-A9F0-00AA0060FA31}"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.zip\CLSID]
  @="{E88DCCE0-B7B3-11d1-A9F0-00AA0060FA31}"
```

Credit to [Shawn Brink](http://www.sevenforums.com) for those scripts.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't disable the message.
You will have to fix the underlying problem: The (possibly corrupted) zip-file.

- Cancel the message box.
- Open the zip-file with a proper zip/unzip application instead of the build-in Windows tools. (E.g. WinZIP, WinRAR or 7-zip.)
- Extract all the files to another folder. (If the ZIP if really corrupt it may not be possible to rescue all files out of it.)
- Delete the ZIP-file.
- If desired: Make a new zip-file and put it back on the USB stick.